# how do I expose the user groups in a public registration-form in joomla?

Tags: joomla

When creating a new account from the front-end I'd like the user to be able to choose a user group in which to register (joomla 2.9). How do I expose the groups I created in the back-end into a registration form, for the users to choose one when registering? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just add the field to your form but the problem is that you would not want to show all of the groups since then people could select super admin or admin.
So what you need to do instead is make a custom field that is more selective.

Comment: Hi Elin. Thank you for taking the time to answer. The web app. I'm trying to make needs four groups of users. The registration process has to happen from the front-end. So, basically I'd like them to pick one of the groups from the registration form. Is there a way to hide the admin and super-user group from the list? Or maybe create a custom drop-down menu with only specific groups they can pick from ?

Comment: I was thinking about this, and I think  I would make a custom form and use the api for adding users to groups to assing them to the specific groups as well as to the default registration group (assuming you want that). Of course if you are not using the groups for acl you could add a field with a profile plugin also.

Comment: Thanks Elin. After researching a few other limitations I've encountered with Joomla, I decided to try to construct my own CMS.